# Entity Framework get CurrentContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm extending an entities' partial class to have a method. How do I get a reference to the  context that the entity is attached to (if any) to get more entities from the same context.

If that's not clear, basically the code I'm looking to write is along these lines (air code):

```
public void AssignSize(int width, int height)
{
    var size = (from s in this.context.Sizes
                where s.width == width && s.height == height
                select s).FirstOrDefault();

    ...
}
```

Nb: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the context to this method, or, better yet, rather than pass in width and height, pass in the size object itself.

Comment: Point taken on the lameness of the example :o)  So no way of doing it without passing the context in? That's a shame.

Comment: Consider this:

var myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.AssignSize(1,2);

This is just one problem with coupling an entity to a particular context.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this article:

[how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx)

It shows a workaround to get the context from an entity.

Comment: Note that this won't work starting with EF6: all entities are simple POCOs that no longer descend from EntityObject and have no knowledge of their context (but their context has knowledge of them).

Comment: This method works with EF6: http://www.apterasoftware.com/Blog/Post/10-10-26/How_To_Get_the_Context_from_an_Entity_Framework_Object.aspx

Comment: @dudeNumber4 that link is broken now

Comment: @RyanDansie I sure wish I could see what that blog post said because it sure seems impossible to me seeins how EF6 entities are simple POCOs.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120202002212/http://www.apterasoftware.com/Blog/Post/10-10-26/How_To_Get_the_Context_from_an_Entity_Framework_Object.aspx  Though not sure if this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

Entities db = new Entities();

Where Entities is the name that you said in EF ...