# EF6 NotMapped Property deserialized outside of request scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

My webapi app is set up to handle multiple database connections by using a `MessageHandler` to set up a db connection based on a request header.  Then I use this connection instance when creating the context.  This part works great.

However, I have a `[NotMapped]` property on most entities which requires a context so that I can run an additional query against the db (obviously, the same db that the entity came from).

The problem is, it appears that webapi finishes up the request before realizing that it has an unmapped property, then dives back into the pipeline to retrieve that property.  However, at that point, I'm back out of my message handlers, my connection instance is not set anymore, and when I try to create the context in the property getter, I get a `NullRefException` from the connection instance.

This is how I see it in my head:
[image]

My first thought was, there's got to be a way to get the context from the entity.  However, in EF6, [all Entities are simply POCOs which have no knowledge of their context.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543457/1579626) (see first comment)

The only thing left that I can think of to do is to manually set an instance of the context in each entity, so that I can reference it in the `NotMapped` property, but that seems sketchy at best.

Am I looking at this the wrong way?
Any suggestions for a solution? (or maybe clarifications on how `NotMapped` properties are actually handled?)

---

**EDIT:** On further examination, it appears that the error is being thrown by the JSON serialization process. (`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`)  So it seems that the IQueryable returned is evaluated during serialization, then it tries to evaluate the `[NotMapped]` property, and fails because the connection instance no longer exists.

I have to assume that what I am trying to accomplish is possible, I'm just not sure how at this point.  **Basically I need the `[NotMapped]' property to know about the context that the entity was created in.**
Suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You are trying to implement manually lazy load inside your POCOs? Do you realize you are missing the point of UoW?

Comment: @JoãoSimões I'm not _manually_ implementing lazy load, I'm using Breeze with WebAPI, which by default returns an IQueryable.  I'm trying to _stay_ with IQueryables (lazy load) so that OData will continue to work.  However, I have some additional data that I need to load for each entity, but my context is lost by the time the IQueryable is evaluated.  My current solution (see answer) is to automatically save a bit of info that I need to re-create the same context (in a multi-connection environment), so that when the IQueryable is evaluated, it knows where to load the additional data from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim this to be the best solution, but since no one has yet suggested anything else, I am posting what I have come up with so far:

What I ended up doing is adding a connectionString variable to my `BaseEntity` class that all my entities derive from.  In the `BaseEntity` *constructor*, I set this property to the current connection string being used (which at this point is in scope) when the entity is created.

Then whenever my `[NotMapped]` property is accessed at a later point (for deserialization or otherwise), I reference the connection property on the entity to create my context with.

Something like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        // Save current connection string being used to create the entity. 
        // ConnectionManager.Instance.CurrentConnection will be null by the time deserialization happens
        _connectionString = ConnectionManager.Instance.CurrentConnection.ConnectionString;
    }

    private readonly string _connectionString;

    [NotMapped]
    public string MyProperty
    {
         using (var ctx = new MyContext(_connectionString))
             ...
    }
}
```

This seems to be working great so far, and I think will be my solution.  Please feel free to suggest any alternate/improved solutions.